# Непонятно как работает сетка на сайте

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь на сайт добавить "бесконечный скролинг": необходимо чтобы при прокрутке страницы вниз загружались новые статьи (Ajax). Всё настроил, но как исправить это баг не пойму: когда загружаются новые статьи, они налазят на уже загруженные.
Сайт на cms Wordpress - http://popsop.com/.

Предположение, что когда загружаются новые посты, они не обрабатываются каким-то скриптом, отвечающего за расположение статьей в "сетке".

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Так у Вас на сайте абсолютное позиционирование каждой новости, и меняются места при ресайзе. JS скрипт меняет, посмотрите, что подключено.

Comment: "JS скрипт меняет"
>>именно это я и понял, а вот какой скрипт за это отвечает не могу найти. Есть ли способ найти скрипт или файл отвечающий за данное позиционирование?

Comment: Так отключите модули в админке по одному. Но зайдя на сайт я так понял вы уже победили.